How do I update the collection correctly to update StateFlow?
In my application, when updating the map StateFlow is not updated. Help me update StateFlow correctly.
data class PageData(val selectedCheckbox: Int, val enable: Boolean)

@HiltViewModel
internal class QwizViewModel @Inject constructor(private val navigationManager: NavigationManager) :
    FeatureViewModel<QwizContract.Event, QwizContract.State, QwizContract.Effect>() {

    private val _mapStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<MutableMap<Int, PageData>>(mutableMapOf())
    val mapStateFlow = _mapStateFlow.asStateFlow()

 private fun onEventSelected(event: QwizContract.Event.ActionsEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is QwizContract.Event.ActionsEvent.SelectAnswer -> {
                _mapStateFlow.value[event.currentPage] = PageData(selectedCheckbox = event.selectedCheckbox, enable = event.enabledBtn)
            }
        }
    }
}

accessing stateflow on screen
val mapState by vm.mapStateFlow.collectAsState()

LaunchedEffect(mapState) {
    selectedIndex = mapState.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.get(currentPage)?.selectedCheckbox ?: -1
}


fun addItem(page: Int, newItem: PageData) {
    val currentItems = _mapStateFlow.value.toMutableMap()
    currentItems[page] = newItem
    _mapStateFlow.value = currentItems
}

fun addItem(page: Int, newItem: PageData) {
    _mapStateFlow.update { currentMap ->
        currentMap.toMutableMap().apply { this[page] = newItem }
    }
}


The issue is that the flow contains a mutable map, it should be immutable instead.
A StateFlow cannot recognize a change when you only mutate the content (i.e. the MutableMap), the content itself must change (i.e. another map is needed).
The first thing to do is to declare the flow like this:
private val _mapStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<Map<Int, PageData>>(emptyMap())

Then you can change its value by using the update function:
fun addItem(page: Int, newItem: PageData) {
    _mapStateFlow.update {
        it + (page to newItem)
    }
}

This adds a new key-value pair to the existing values and returns the result as a new map. Since the new value is a different map now it will properly trigger all subscribers, like the collectAsState() in your composable.
